# Migrating SBS 2003 to 2012 standard

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, migration, windows-sbs-2003

My company is currently trying to migrate a Windows Small Business Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012. We know the general procedure, but we want to make sure we aren't going to mess anything up tremendously. Here's the steps we were planning on taking:

1. Uninstall exchange

2. Remove legacy GPO's

3. Demote the domain controller

4. Promote the new server to the primary domain controller.

We have no mail servers to worry about. My question is, will the above method work or will we need to make a complete new domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've asked the question implies that you haven't done any more than the most superficial research or planning.

Your proposed approach will flatten, destroy, delete, remove your domain at step 3 when you demote the last (only) DC.

Also this is a duplicate question:
[SBS 2003 to Server 2012 Standard - Migration Protocol](https://serverfault.com/questions/486411/sbs-2003-to-server-2012-standard-migration-protoocol)